# PHP String - Remove Array or Words & Check for Others

Tags: php, arrays, string, match

I have a String:

```
$data = "String contains works like apples, peaches, banana, bananashake, appletart";
```

I also have 2 std arrays as follows that contain a number of words:

```
$profanityTextAllowedArray = array();
$profanityTextNotAllowedArray = array();
```

eg:

```
$profanityTextAllowedArray
(
    [0] => apples
    [1] => kiwi
    [2] => mango
    [3] => pineapple
)
```

How can I take the string `$data` and first remove any words from the `$profanityTextAllowedArray` and then check the string `$data` for any words in the `$profanityTextNotAllowedArray` which should be flagged?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Something like this can help you:

```php
$data = "apples, peaches, banana, bananashake, appletart";

$allowedWords = array('apples', 'peaches', 'banana');
$notAllowedWords = array('foo', 'appletart', 'bananashake');

$allowedWordsFilteredString = preg_replace('/\b('.implode('|', $allowedWords).')\b/', '', $data);

$wordsThatNeedsToBeFlagged = array_filter($notAllowedWords, function ($word) use ($allowedWordsFilteredString) {
    return false !== strpos($allowedWordsFilteredString, $word);
});

var_dump($wordsThatNeedsToBeFlagged);
```

Comment: If list of allowed or filtered words will get bigger, this will use a lot of CPU. We should always think of such cases, even while learning.

Comment: @Megakuh that's interesting. Are you poiting on the use of the pReg library or is there some other heavy CPU thing in here?

Answer (score 3):

```
$list = explode( ' ', $data );

foreach( $list as $key => $word ) {
  $cleanWord = str_replace( array(','), '', $word ); // Clean word from commas, etc.
  if( !in_array( $cleanWord, $profanityTextAllowedArray ) ) {
    unset($list[$key]);
  }
}

$newData = implode( ' ', $list );
```

Let me know if it is clear.

Comment: wouldn't the use of [`trim`](http://php.net/trim) nicer instead of `str_replace` to clean up the words?